# Is there any better way of handling multiple file input in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a way of handling multiple file inputs in reactjs while setting the state but I am not sure if there is any better way of doing.

```
handleChangeM = (files) => {
        console.log("handle change ", files);
        this.setState({
            file: this.state.file.concat(Array.from(files))
        })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use prevState for setting state. here is an example for detail

```
import React from "react";

export default class FileUploadExample extends React.Component {

    state = {
        files: []
    };

    fileUpload = (e) => {
        let files = [...e.target.files];
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {files: [...prevState.files, ...files]}
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>File Upload</span>
                <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file" onChange={this.fileUpload}/>
                <ul>
                    {
                        this.state.files.map((file, i) => <li key={i}>{file.name}</li>)
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```